# Android TV with Nougat+ on and trying to intercept key events with talkback accessibility on

Tags: java, android, android-7.0-nougat, android-tv

I'm not sure if anyone has come across this issue but I noticed that Android versions 7+ seem to have the talkback accessibility service written different in a way. Now what happens is the app has no chance of getting a hold of what directional key is being pressed as I've tried overriding the dispatchKeyEvent method or anything related to it. Does anyone know if there other things I need to set in order to capture which directional keypress is fired or is my only choice is to write my own custom accessibility service?

Edit: Sorry forgot to mention that I lose the ability to track directional key events when the talkback accessibility has been turned on

Comment: AFAIK, there are [new features and improvements](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html) applied which intends to improve the usability of the platform including [accessibility](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#accessibility).

Comment: Thanks I've read over that and supposedly I shouldn't need any code changes but the talkback service seems to be written to swallow the key event handler. I'm surprised that the earlier version of android with talkback on the key events get propagated to the native app to get a chance to handle it. It really seems I have no choice of the matter but needing to write out my own Accessibility service out or trick the system to pretend it's shifting focus. I know I am breaking the rules provided by [WCAG 2.0] (https://www.w3.org/TR/mobile-accessibility-mapping/) but google made our app useless now